# Generic endpoint for REST resources in Perl Catalyst

Tags: perl, rest, catalyst

I have several REST resource endpoints defined, such as `/user`, `/group`, and `/event`, as separate controllers. They all inherit from a root controller (`App::Web::Controller::Root`). Is it possible to create a generic endpoint for all these resources within the root controller that is able to identify the resource type?

My main use-case is `.../list`, which I'd like to define generically, which would identify its parent resource and return an array of resource entities. For instance,

```
/user/list      # Array list of user entities
/group/list     # Array list of group entities
/event/list     # Array list of event entities
```

I can easily create an action that inverts the resources (e.g., `/list/event` is naturally handled by `sub list_GET`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An approach I'm using for identifying the resource is to have each resource controller define its resource in the stash, and then have the generic action reference that stash value.

For example, in each of the resource controllers:

```
package App::Web::Controller::User;

sub begin :Auto {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    $c->stash(resource => 'User');
}
```

Then, in the root controller:

```
package App::Web::Controller::Root;

sub list :Path('list') :ActionClass('REST') {}

sub list_GET {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    my $resource = $c->stash->{resource};
    return $self->status_ok($c, entity => {
        list => [ $c->model('App::' . $resource)->find->all ]
    });
}
```

I am not very happy with this because it's not generic enough, as it requires every controller to define its resource.